# need solutions with some code of limit and order by in mysql query function

Tags: mysql, arrays, count, limit

I have table like this

```sql
|post_date |post      |value    |
---------------------------------
|2019-11-05|post      |text     |
|2019-11-05|post      |text     |
|2019-11-05|post      |text     |
|2019-11-05|post      |text     |
|2019-11-06|post      |text     |
|2019-11-06|post      |text     |
|2019-11-07|post      |text     |
|2019-11-08|post      |text     |
|2019-11-08|post      |text     |
|2019-11-08|post      |text     |
|2019-11-08|post      |text     |
|2019-11-08|post      |text     |
|2019-11-08|post      |text     |
```

i have tried to select like this

```sql
SELECT post_date, count(*) as post FROM myTable GROUP BY post_date ORDER BY post_date ASC LIMIT 3
```

it will show like this

```sql
|post_date |post      |
-----------------------
|2019-11-05|4         |
|2019-11-06|2         |
|2019-11-07|1         |
```

what i need here like this one

```sql
|post_date |post      |
-----------------------
|2019-11-06|2         |
|2019-11-07|1         |
|2019-11-08|6         |
```

its look like limit 3 result from behind. it will get latest 3 result from order, not oldest one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your current query in a subquery to impose the ascending date order you want:

```
SELECT
    post_date,
    post
FROM
(
    SELECT post_date, COUNT(*) AS post
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY post_date
    ORDER BY post_date DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t
ORDER BY post_date;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Comment: uppsss, i wrong when set variable in first select ```(post_date)``` i change into ```(date)```, so unknown column date on my record.

Comment: ty for helping me